# C++: Is there a way to create a templated namespace?

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, c++11

I was wondering if it would be possible to do the following:

```
template <typename T>
namespace basic_foo {
    struct str {
        T value;
    };
}

basic_foo<char>::str s1;
namespace foo = basic_foo<char>;
foo::str s2;
```

Is it possible to do this in any c++ compiler?
Is there work being done to implement this?
I think that it would be a great addition to the language.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you just make a templated struct inside the namespace

Comment: This would be a nice feature to have.

Answer (score 10):

No, you cannot define a namespace template.  You can, however, achieve almost exactly what you want (with only slightly different syntax), by making `basic_foo` a class template:

```
template <typename T>
struct basic_foo {
    struct str {
        T value;
    };
};

basic_foo<char>::str s1;
typedef basic_foo<char> foo;
foo::str s2;
```

Comment: Close, but no argument-dependent lookup.

Comment: @BenVoigt:  `basic_foo<T>::str` can declare friends, which will be found via ADL. (You are right, though, it's not _exactly_ the same.)

Comment: Yes, but functions defined inside `basic_foo<T>` won't be found by ADL... they would be if `basic_foo` were a real namespace.  You can put them in the parent namespace instead, but you lose access to the template arguments and have to respecify them all over.

Comment: @BenVoigt:  Right, I agree.  But, such functions can be declared as friends in `basic_foo<T>::str`.  (For another difference:  types and templates can only be defined once, namespaces may be reopened multiple times.)

Comment: Would friends of `basic_foo<T>` be found also when the argument is a `basic_foo<T>::str`?  One considers the case of a reusable algorithm that should be implemented once for use with several different types nested inside `basic_foo<T>`.

Comment: @BenVoigt:  Yes, friends of `basic_foo<T>` would be found.  See https://gist.github.com/3061359.  g++ 4.7 and Visual C++ 2012 RC both accept it (which is usually a good sign).

Comment: awesome.  Too bad I can't +1 this answer a second time.

Comment: @BenVoigt:  To be honest, though, I was surprised when both compilers accepted that.  I was sure it wouldn't work.  Time for some research... :-)

Comment: Although classes can't be reopened, nested classes can be forward declared and then defined in a different file.

Comment: @James: Well, those friend functions become members of the enclosing namespace, which is the same enclosing namespace as of the nested classes, so it makes sense that they would be searched.

Comment: Another difference is that you can't use a using-directive inside the struct.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: The friend approach is close but not exactly the same. A free function friend declaration provides a declaration of a namespace level function but only within the enclosing class. The corner case now moves to the fact that at friend defined inside the class definition (and not explicitly declared at namespace level) can *only* be found by ADL, which in turn means that you cannot obtain a pointer to it, which in turn means that you cannot pass it to algorithms...

Comment: Yes.  It also has the added disadvantage of injecting the names into the _enclosing_ namespace, so siblings of `basic_foo` can also be used to call the function (yet another way this isn't exactly like a namespace).

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: I don't think that is the case. Because the friend function is being defined within the type, if there is no explicit declaration in the enclosing namespace it will not be available (this is the advantage and disadvantage of this approach). `friend` has this particular feature of being able to *define* a function at namespace level that is not accessible at that level. In `struct X { friend void f() {} };` the function `f` is unreachable as it is not declared in the namespace and ADL won't find it as `X` is not an argument to the function (which would trigger lookup inside `X`)

Comment: To some extent, the *symbol* is injected into the enclosing namespace, but the *name* is not.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas:  Re-reading the name lookup specification, I agree with you. However, g++ 4.7 and Visual C++ 2012 accept the following program:  https://gist.github.com/3062915.  Maybe I'm missing something.  Or maybe both compilers are wrong.  It wouldn't be the first time (for either of those: me being wrong or the compilers being wrong :-D).

Answer (score 5):

No, but you can use templated struct:

```
template<typename T>
struct basic_foo
{
    struct str
    {
        T value;
    };
};

typedef basic_foo<char> foo;
foo::str s1;
```

You could also use `class` instead of `struct`, but you would have to remember about `public:` in such case.

Answer (score 1):

No. It`s impossible, namespace template is unreal, but you can make class template.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers explain how to do what it looks like you might want.  But it sounds like you have a different idea of what a namespace is for than what it really is designed for.

namespace solves the problem of two unrelated C++ code bases being able to communicate with each other.  C doesn't have namespaces and is much more verbose as a result.  Try using a 3rd party library such as openssl or oauth in C.  You'll find a lot of function calls like this:

```
openssl_create
openssl_connect
```

and so on.  And this is really, really important.  Because chances are I want to write a function called `connect`.  And so does the author of the ZMQ library I used.  And so forth.  And it's a major, major pain to have two functions with the same name trying to be called in the same place...

namespace is purely a software engineering construct, not a programming one.  It lets the prefix `openssl_` simply become the namespace so code like the above can intermingle more freely.  Why don't namespaces conflict?  This is where software engineering becomes even more human and social, as essentially the global programming community must make sure this doesn't happen.  Generally outer namespaces are usually companies; I would guess all Google internal code is in namespace `Google`.  Java solves this by promoting the convention of naming package (like namespace) by the internet domain name, which is presumably a real-world entity that can't conflict, e.g. Google code should live in package `com.google...`

I should also note that within an organization namespaces are used at the application, or product, or team level - e.g. Google Drive probably has a function "upload" somewhere as does Google Mail, and those teams might generally not talk to each other...  but still need to write intermingling code.
That's what namespaces do.  Nothing more, nothing less.